# Whats the sharepoint rest endpoint to get a web by its id

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013

I have a webid and a listid in a sharepoint page. I'm trying to construct a rest url to get to the list.

I cant figure out the url to get the web given the WebID.

I tried 
https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/web/webs(guid'33213c5c-30e5-468c-87f7-52b48a7b6a3d')
https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/web/webs('33213c5c-30e5-468c-87f7-52b48a7b6a3d')
https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/web/webs/GetById('33213c5c-30e5-468c-87f7-52b48a7b6a3d')

How do I get at the web with that id? I need to get a list in the web.
I was thinking it was going to be as simple as 
https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/web/webs(guid'33213c5c-30e5-468c-87f7-52b48a7b6a3d')/lists(guid'the-list-id'), but I cant get at the web!

++++++++++++++++ mReply to vadim ++++++++++++++++++++++++

Thanks Vadim,
You got me pointed in the right direction

This url will get me to the web:
https://xxx.sharepoint.com/_api/web/webs?$filter=iD eq guid'33213c5c-30e5-468c-87f7-52b48a7b6a3d'

This url will get me all items in all lists in all webs
https://xxx.sharepoint.com/_api/web/webs?$expand=lists,lists/items

This url will get me all items in all lists in a specified web:
https://xxx.sharepoint.com/_api/web/webs?$expand=lists,lists/items&$filter=iD eq guid'33213c5c-30e5-468c-87f7-52b48a7b6a3d'

But how doe I get all items in a specified list in a specified web?
This doesnt work:
https://xxx.sharepoint.com/_api/web/webs?$expand=lists,lists/items&$filter=((iD eq guid'33213c5c-30e5-468c-87f7-52b48a7b6a3d' ) and (Lists/Id eq guid'd38444af-dd7f-404b-9e75-b1f8c6cdee7d' ))

Its a valid Web id and a valid list id, but sharepoint complains :m:message xml:lang="en-US">Field or property "Id" does not exist.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Web resource could be retrieved  using `$filter` query option as demonstrated below:

```
/_api/web/webs?$filter=ID eq guid'c01e1b4a-e671-431d-97aa-4b02a57803c7'
```

In order to retrieve the corresponding List resource by id you could consider the following approach:

1. Perform request to get `Web` Url by its Id:
   `/_api/web/webs?$select=ServerRelativeUrl&$filter=ID eq
   guid'c01e1b4a-e671-431d-97aa-4b02a57803c7'`
2. Get List by id:  `{web url}/_api/Web/Lists(guid'b778bbec-dd69-4a6c-9437-c73972c36292')`

where `{web url}` is web site url found in the first request

Comment: thanks vadim, Stack overflow wouldn't let me leave a comment as it was too long. I added my comment to the original question.

Comment: This answer assumes the web guid relates to a child web. If the could be either web is a sub-site of a sub-site or the root web it will not return the WebURL. Approach outlined in the following answer might be more appropraite. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51625516/247298