# SharePoint Get all sites and all sub sites using SharePoint online REST API

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

For SharePoint Online connector We used following steps to fetch all sites:

**Step 1:** Created Add-in on SharePoint instance with following permission xml

```
<AppPermissionRequests>
        <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl"/>
        <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="Read"/>
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

**Step 2:**     Used below API to get all sites and subsites

```
https://<site_name>.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:STS_Site' &rowlimit=100
```

**Issue we are facing** –

1. Above endpoint is returning all `sites, sub sites along with user’s
   personal site(One drive)`, while we need all `sites and sub sites`
   only.
2. Please suggest **minimal required permission to read all site, all subsite, all folders and files metadata**

We referred following links:

- http://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/add-in-permissions-in-sharepoint
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a path filter in the endpoint.

Normal site collections have a path like `https://tenant.sharepoint.com` whereas personal (One Drive) site collections have path like `https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/*`.

So, modify your endpoint as below:

```
https://<site_name>.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:STS_Site
Path:"https://<site_name>.sharepoint.com/*"'&rowlimit=500
```

This will only return site collections starting with `https://<site_name>.sharepoint.com` path and will exclude the One Drive site collections which are on a different path.

Comment: Thanks Gautam `<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl"/>`
Could you please correct me on the Add-in permission part. I need to set read permission only. please check updated question
Thanks

Comment: If its just for display/retrieval purposes, then read permission would be enough. But if you need to do more processing on it, then you will need higher permissions

Comment: yes, its only for /retrieval. I think following permissions would be sufficient.
`<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/search" Right="QueryAsUserIgnoreAppPrincipal"/>
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="Read"/>` 

Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 3):

A way from Joel Dsouza for your reference.

**1.The First Ajax is to get the Root Site Title and the Relative URL.**

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/site/rootweb?$select=Title,ServerRelativeUrl",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(rootsite) {

    },
    error: function(rootsite) {},
    async: false
});
```

**2.The Second AJAX is to get all the sub sites under the Root Site.**

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/webinfos?$select=ServerRelativeUrl,Title",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(subsites) {
        $.each(subsites.d.results, function() {
            getSubSites(this.ServerRelativeUrl, this.Title);
        });

    },
    error: function(subsites) {},
    async: false
});
```

**3.This is a Recursive Function to loop through the sub sites and check for more sub sites.**

```
function getSubSites(SubSiteUrl, SubSiteTitle) {
    console.log(SubSiteUrl);
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + SubSiteUrl + "/_api/web/webinfos?$select=ServerRelativeUrl,Title",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function(subsites) {

            $.each(subsites.d.results, function(index) {
                getSubSites(this.ServerRelativeUrl, this.Title);
            });
        },
        error: function(subsites) {},
        async: false
    });
}
```

More information: [Get All Sites and Sub Sites using REST API](https://www.dsouzajoel.com/2016/02/10/get-all-sites-and-sub-sites-using-rest-api/)

Comment: I don't want to hit multiple API for that.
As suggested by @gautam I am able to get expected result.
Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
https://yoursharepointsite.com/_api/search/query?querytext='(contentclass:STS_Site) (contentclass:STS_Web)'&trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=5000&selectproperties='Title,Url,Path,ParentLink'"
```

The above rest url shoul give you all the Sites and subsite the user has access to. You may need to trim duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the id of the hub site
and use this
_api/search/query?querytext='Title:*  contentclass:STS_Site contentclass:STS_Web  DepartmentId:{yourhubsiteid} path:[yoursiteaddress]'&selectproperties='Title,sitelogo,path,description,Departmentid'&rowlimit=2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).